# how to determine orientation of an element? - engineering mechanics

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

In mechanics, we always just assume the initial element orientation to be parallel to the surface. In practice how do we define it? Can we always make this assumption? Why or why not?

I would assume it to deal with grain or the orientation in which materials were cut as well?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Surface of what? Earth? Moon? some arbitrary one?

Comment: The premise is incorrect; we don't "always" take a differential element to have a face parallel to a surface. However, we might prefer it for convenience, if the element lies at the surface and the surface stress is known (e.g., zero for an unloaded free surface).

Comment: Have you never seen any machine's exploded parts diagram?